# Scrolling QTableWidget smoothly BY MOUSE WHEEL

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I tried `.setVerticalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)` which works nicely but requires user to move mouse to the scroll bar and use it to experience the smooth scroll but the mouse wheel works the old way with jumpy scrolling, i wonder if there a way to make the scrolling behave the same when using the mouse wheel ?

Comment: Wheel movement usually scrolls *instantly* by a specific amount, depending on the system and user configuration. Can you be more clear about what you mean by "smooth scrolling"? Do you mean an "animation" that shows the contents scrolling, instead of directly skipping to the new position? Because if that's the case, it's a different thing (and what you call "move mouse to the scroll bar and use it to experience smooth scroll" is *not* that).

Comment: @musicamante the mouse wheel jumps like 120 steps at once and changing the scroll bar steps per scroll doesn't change the wheel's, the solution below solved it.

Comment: @Ahmed4end No. The wheel event scrolls by the amount of the singleStep, based on the [`angleDelta()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwheelevent.html#angleDelta) (which *normally* is 120 units, but could be less for high resolution mice), and the singleStep is changed each time the view is resized or its contents are changed. For item views, the singleStep is based on the viewport size divided by the amount of rows shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use self.widget.verticalScrollBar().setSingleStep(step).

QTableWidget inherits QTableView, which inherits QAbstractItemView, which inherits QAbstractScrollArea, which has method verticalScrollBar(), which brings us to the QScrollBar Class that inherits QAbstractSlider, which finally has setSingleStep(step) method (maybe there is shorter path?).

Here's the complete code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Scrolling QTableWidget smoothly BY MOUSE WHEEL")
        
        label = QLabel("singleStep:")
        self.spinbox = QSpinBox()
        self.spinbox.setValue(1)
        self.spinbox.setMinimum(1)
        self.spinbox.setMaximum(200)
        self.spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.on_value_changed)

        self.widget = QTableWidget(100, 5)

        for i in range(100):
            for j in range(5):
                self.widget.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(str(i+j)))

        self.widget.setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
        #self.widget.verticalScrollBar().setSingleStep(1)
        self.set_single_step()

        spinbox_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        spinbox_layout.addStretch()
        spinbox_layout.addWidget(label)
        spinbox_layout.addWidget(self.spinbox)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(spinbox_layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def on_value_changed(self, step):
        self.set_single_step()

    def set_single_step(self):
        self.widget.verticalScrollBar().setSingleStep(self.spinbox.value())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

You can increase/decrease step in spinbox to see how it behaves. I hope that is what you asked for.